# reposition object in circle

Tags: java, libgdx, mathematics, trigonometry

As you can see on the image, I have a p1 and p2 objects with (x,y) coordinates which I know the values, and I know radius of all these circle objects.

However, I want to calculate new position x,y which would be p3 center point. Basically, as you can see it's p2 position + radius.

I am doing this for java game which is based on libgdx. I would appreciate any math or java language directions/examples.

[image]

Comment: This looks like just [Cosine Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to work out the angle at the tip of the triangle P1P2P3, and then the [Unit Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) to get the coordinates of the point at that angle. Each of these topics is covered extensively in online math and geometry tutorials. How have you tried to solve this problem, given your research of these resources to date? What new gamedev-specific insight do you need here?

Comment: Thank you I will have a look at this.

Comment: @Kapparino You could also take a look at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/84115/libgdx-point-that-scrolls-on-the-edge-of-a-circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For circle `p2` and `p3` to be close enough to eachother to touch, we know that the distance between them must be `2 * rs` (where `rs` is the radius of the small circles).

If we then construct a triangle from the points `p1`, `p2` and `p3`, we can divide that triagle in the middle and know that the short side of the triangle is equal to `rs`

[image]

Using the sine rule we can then figure out the angle at the center of the big circle as we have a triangle where we know two of the sides (`r` and `rs`) and one angle (the 90 degree angle we get from splitting the triangle in half).

This angle times two is the angle between `p2` and `p3`

`angle = 2.0 * asin(rs / r)`

Since we can get the angle of a `Vector2` in **libGDX** it's then easy to find the angle of `p2` and then add the `angle` calculated above, as shown in this example where the green circle is moved around and the blue position is calculated using the above method:

[image]

Full source code for a **libGDX** example:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class SandboxGame extends Game {
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/(float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(10.0f, 10.0f * aspectRatio);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    float b;
    @Override
    public void render() {
        b += 32.0f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);

        float r = 1.0f;
        float rs = 0.4f;
        Vector2 p1 = new Vector2(1, 0.5f);
        Vector2 p2 = new Vector2(r, 0).rotateDeg(b).add(p1);
        float angleToP2 = new Vector2(p2).sub(p1).angleRad();
        float angle = 2.0f * MathUtils.asin(rs / r);
        Vector2 p3 = new Vector2(r, 0).rotateRad(angleToP2 + angle).add(p1);


        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.circle(p1.x, p1.y, r, 32);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        shapeRenderer.circle(p2.x, p2.y, rs, 32);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        shapeRenderer.circle(p3.x, p3.y, rs, 32);
        shapeRenderer.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detail description.

Comment: Not a problem @Kapparino, I hope it helped.